# Cerium 140 into Cerium 141 via use of ceria powder?

Tags: nuclear-physics, physical-chemistry

I was reading a PDF [Cerium 141 production](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271658895_Production_of_cerium-141_using_ceria_and_nanoceria_powder_a_potential_radioisotope_for_simultaneous_therapeutic_and_diagnostic_applications), that stated cerium 141 productions via ceria powder. My question is how is the Cerium 141 actually created via using standard ceria powder?

Answer (score 4):

As the article states, it's done by exposing the $^{140}\text{Ce}$ to neutrons.

Using the Evaluated Nuclear Data File site (https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/exfor/endf00.jsp) one can pull up the neutron cross sections. Below are shown the total cross section (all neutron scattering paths) and the $^{140}\text{Ce}$ (n,$\gamma$) $^{141}\text{Ce}$ cross section. Clearly thermal neutrons from a reactor are the way to go.

[image: neutron cross sections for the reaction]

As for the resulting gamma spectrum, you go to the Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data File tab (https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/) and pull up the measured energies and intensities of the gamma from the reaction:

[image: gamma levels]

As a bonus, it actual is hard to make lots of $^{141}\text{Ce}$ since it turns out that the $^{141}\text{Ce}$ (n,$\gamma$) $^{142}\text{Ce}$ cross section is more than 10x larger than the $^{140}\text{Ce}$ (n,$\gamma$) $^{141}\text{Ce}$ cross section:

[image: 141 to 142 cross section]

This means that once you get to about 10 percent $^{141}\text{Ce}$ in your powder, you are turning it into $^{142}\text{Ce}$ as fast as you are making it.

Comment: what do they do to expose it, thats why I'm confused. thanks for the quick response.

Comment: The notation $(\text{n},\gamma)$ means a neutron goes in and a gamma ray comes out.

Comment: @aw - one would assume using a reactor. However, you could look at the cross section on ENDF.

Comment: @BenCrowell - If you want, I could edit in an ENDF cross section plot and the ENSDF gamma info. Seems a bit much to add without your agreement...